# How to list the most frequent 3-word strings on Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a list of industries with a adjacent list of industries to categorize them. I would like to know which industries are the most common but I don't manage to make Sheets interpret two-word categories as one.

First, I would like to know which 5 categories are the most common overall. Also I would like to know the top 5 one-word (black), two-word (red) and three-word (blue) categories.

Plus, I would like to get rid of the commas.

Here's what I want to achieve and a link to a google sheets document where I've laid out all the data:

[image: Document Screenshot]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13N8gc4POPhFhTvyqq-UugWS5GCgcONwliacSL8-MAr8/edit#gid=0

How can these categories be grouped and listed?

Comment: can you make the sheet editable so it's a little eaiser to demo/test solutions?

Comment: I just did, @MattKing. I completely forgot, sorry.

Comment: @MattKing you probably already know, but to let everyone know, you can press `File->Make a copy` on any spreadsheet to be able to edit an otherwise locked sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overal word:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B11&",",,99^99), ", ")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

---

overall phrase:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B11&",",,99^99), ",")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

---

one word:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B11&",",,99^99), ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1)
  where not Col1 contains ' '
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

---

two words:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B11&",",,99^99), ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1)
  where Col1 matches '\w+ \w+'
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

three words:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(B3:B11&",",,99^99), ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1)
  where Col1 matches '\w+ \w+ \w+'
  group by Col1
  order by count(Col1) desc
  limit 5
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

Comment: matches seems to be a dangerous Query string, I'm surprised it even works here, it seems when you use the | in Query matches it only runs locally and not on the google server.

Comment: It seems to work wonders. Is there any way I could use this formula to do this exact same operation but with actual sentences? In that case, I would like to omit obvious words that are used a lot in language like articles, pronouns, most common verbs, etc. Ideally, I would like to have a combination of adverbs, adjectives and nouns. If this is possible, any chance you could point me to the right direction?

Comment: @djur You should ask a separate question that is more specific with an sample of behavior you desire.

Comment: @CodeCamper, I just did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61075050/identifying-adverb-adjective-noun-strings-in-a-list-of-sentences-on-google-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the problem into 3 formulas will allow you to support as many "words" as you want.

Step 1) put formula in `D29` treat all the words as a single word *(looking at your question it seems like this is the only step you really need)*

```
=query(arrayformula(trim(substitute(transpose(split(query({substitute(B3:B," ","_")},"select * where Col1 is not null",counta(B3:B)),", ")),"_"," "))),"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Descriptions', count(Col1) 'Frequency'")
```

Step 2) put formula in `F29` Place this next formula next to the table produced by the formula above. `D30:D` should be replaced if you use different ranges.

```
=arrayformula({"Words";if(D30:D="","",1+LEN(D30:D)-len(SUBSTITUTE(D30:D," ","")))})
```

Step 3) put formula in `G29` This will output the largest frequency ordered by word count `D29:F` should be replaced if you use different locations

```
=query({D29:F},"select * where Col1 is not null order by Col3,Col2 desc")
```

The advantage to doing it this way is you support 1,2,3,4... word frequency.

Comment: Whereas Step 1 does one of the things I want to achieve, I am unsure as to what the other two steps are really doing. Could you please explain further? I've compiled your answer in the page "Copy II" in the same document.

Comment: @djur try putting step 1 in cell `D29` see the edit I included the cell to put the formula

Comment: I've just realized how your code works. Quick question: how can I modify the code to exclude certain values such as a preposition or a certain verb?