# Recognizing language patterns in a list of sentences on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, nlp, transpose, google-sheets-query

I am trying to analyze a series of sentences by identifying the most common adverb-adjective-noun strings. I have managed [to get answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066823/how-to-list-the-most-frequent-3-word-strings-on-google-sheets) for how to do so with random words but I think this is a standalone question, and it might better to be dealt with separately.

In this case, I would like to omit common word types like personal pronouns, articles, prepositions and even verbs. Ideally, the results should produce:

- Most common nouns
- Most common adjectives
- Most common adverbs
- Most common adjective+noun strings
- Most common adverb+noun strings

I understand there is a way to do this by using [an online dictionary](https://caninfotech.com/office-suites/find-noun-verb-adjective-google-spreadsheet/) but I have been unable   to integrate that in my code to get the results I want. Is there any way of automating this without listing all the words that you want omitted? How could it be done?

Here's a link to [the spreadsheet I'm using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13N8gc4POPhFhTvyqq-UugWS5GCgcONwliacSL8-MAr8/edit#gid=1730288025) (for this particular query, see page 2) and a screenshot of the types of text I would like to analyze with a manual color-coded visualization of what I want to achieve:

[image: Sample text and visualization of the desired results]

Comment: But there seems to be a way to recognize the grammar category:

https://caninfotech.com/office-suites/find-noun-verb-adjective-google-spreadsheet/

Comment: Just a side note to this question, you do realize nouns, adjectives and adverbs can also be part of personal names... for example "Advanced Micro Devices"

Comment: I understand that. In the sample text I created in the spreadsheet, there is no proper name that is comes up twice but they should appear in the results list as well.

Comment: So you want Advanced Micro Devices to be quadruple counted... Advanced, Micro, Devices, Micro Devices etc?

Comment: I don't mind them being quadruple counted. I would like to use a solution that allows me to recognize common language patterns. Do you think this could somehow be achived?

Comment: Is this a google sheets question or a general programming question, without some sort of progress and specificity of what you want to do this might not be an appropriate stackoverflow question